# Access "table$partitions" through Spark Sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-athena

I figured out that running the following code will do full scan of the table:

```
select max(run_id) from database.table
```

So I switched my code to work with the following syntax:

```
select max(run_id) from "database"."table$partitions"
```

This query works great on Athena but when I try to execute it with Spark Sql I get the following error:

```
mismatched input '"database"' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 24)
```

It seems like spark sql identify the quotes as the end of the query. 
Any ideas how to make this query work on spark sql?
Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question with the spark script that you have used?

Comment: How about `select max(run_id) from "database"."table" where <partitions condition here>`?

Comment: @pltc run_id is the partition so I can't filter on him if I want to get the max value. And getting max value executing full scan on the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this problem was:

```
sql_context.sql(f'show partitions {table_name}').agg(
    f.max(f.regexp_extract('partition', rf'''{partition_name}=([^/]+)''', 1))).collect()[0][0]
```

The advantage: It's not doing full scan on the table 
Disadvantage: It's scan all partitions levels + code isn't elegant.
Anyway that's the best I found